# Run ringtone with notification

Tags: android

I need to play some music when I send a notification on Android, but I'm having the problem that while the music plays, the application is locked. I can't do a thing, neither start an activity, scroll nor go back. I can minimize the app and do other thing with the audio still playing (the audio might last 2 minutes, so I can't let this happen).

I tried to implement this in different kind of threads that android has, with no success.

With Handler and AsyncTask, it happens what I said up here. With regular thread it doesn't play any sound. The code with Handler is like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
        r.play();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setSound(soundUri)` method on your `Notification.Builder` like so:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSound(soundUri);
```